# Locally Unique?

Tags: xsd

I am trying to get straight the unique and key elements for XML Schema,
especially with regards to the selector and field elements within.

I'm unclear about selectors and fields, and I need to get this straight.

Suppose I had an XML file with companies listed within functional groups.
I have an element within each group with a unique field (to reference
each particular group).

I want to create a unique field within each company listing within
each group that would be unique only within that particular group.

Would this be correct?:

```
    <xs:unique id="company_group_refs" name="company_group_refs">
        <xs:selector xpath="root/all_companies/company_group"/>
        <xs:field xpath="company_group_ref"/>
    </xs:unique>

    <xs:unique id="company_refs" name="company_refs">
        <xs:selector xpath="root/all_companies/company_group"/>
        <xs:field xpath="company/company_ref"/>
    </xs:unique>
```

If so, could I condense the above to this?:

```
    <xs:unique id="company_refs" name="company_refs">
        <xs:selector xpath="root/all_companies/company_group"/>
        <xs:field xpath="company_group_ref"/>
        <xs:field xpath="company/company_ref"/>
    </xs:unique>
```

To reference any company name in particular, I want to be able to
give an XPath expression like this:

root/all_companies/company_group[company_group_ref=x1]/company[company_ref=x2]/name

Where: x1 = the unique reference for the company group.
and:   x2 = the unique reference for the company within that group.

What follows is an XML file excerpt that exemplifies this scenario:

```
<all_companies>

    <company_group>
        <company_group_name>Cleaning</company_group_name>
        <company_group_ref>1</company_group_ref>
        <company>
            <name>Ajax</name>
            <company_ref>1</company_ref>
        </company>
        <company>
            <name>Bloomburg</name>
            <company_ref>2</company_ref>
        </company>
        <company>
            <name>Morris</name>
            <company_ref>3</company_ref>
        </company>
    </company_group>

    <company_group>
        <company_group_name>Electrical</company_group_name>
        <company_group_ref>2</company_group_ref>
        <company>
            <name>Armstrong</name>
            <company_ref>1</company_ref>
        </company>
        <company>
            <name>Bloomburg</name>
            <company_ref>2</company_ref>
        </company>
        <company>
            <name>Zap Electrical</name>
            <company_ref>3</company_ref>
        </company>
        <company>
            <name>Morris</name>
            <company_ref>4</company_ref>
        </company>
    </company_group>

</all_companies>
```

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint to require uniqueness of group_refs is correct. The constraint to make company_refs unique within a group should read like this

```
<xs:element name="company_group">
  <xs:unique name="company_unique_within_group">
    <xs:selector xpath="company">
    <xs:field xpath="company_ref">
  </xs:unique>
  ...
</xs:element>
```

Read that as "within a company_group" "select all company" and require that "company_ref is unique among them".

Your company_ref constraint says: "globally" "for all company_groups" require that "company/company_ref is unique".

Your condensed constraint expresses something entirely different: "globally" "for all company_groups" require that "the combination of company_group_ref and company/company_ref" is unique". Given that there are actually multiple company_refs per group, the latter two are nonsensical.

Comment: Hi Martin!    Thanks for the response, and the answer.    It makes sense.